# Pandas Series Resample

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have the following pandas series:

```
    dummy_array = pd.Series(np.array(range(-10, 11)), index=(np.array(range(0, 21))/10))
```

This yield the following array:

```
0.0   -10
0.1    -9
0.2    -8
0.3    -7
0.4    -6
0.5    -5
0.6    -4
0.7    -3
0.8    -2
0.9    -1
1.0     0
1.1     1
1.2     2
1.3     3
1.4     4
1.5     5
1.6     6
1.7     7
1.8     8
1.9     9
2.0    10
```

If I want to resample, how can I do it? I read the docs and it suggested this:

```
    dummy_array.resample('20S').mean()
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Edit:

I want my final vector to have double the frequency. So something like this:

```
0.0   -10
0.05   -9.5
0.1    -9
0.15    -8.5
0.2    -8
0.25    -7.5
etc.
```

Comment: from the `pandas.DataFrame.resample` docs: "Object must have a datetime-like index (DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex, or TimedeltaIndex), or pass datetime-like values to the on or level keyword."

Comment: You can get what you want with a different grouper, maybe `pd.cut` or integer division. What bins do you like to form? '20 seconds' doesn't really make sense (unless you mean to interpret those numbers as seconds)

Comment: Actually what I want is to Upsample my initial array to double. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your contributions. After looking at the answers and thinking a bit more I found a more generic solution that should handle every possible case. In this case, I wanted to upsample dummy_arrayA to the same index as dummy_arrayB. What I did was to create a new index which has both A and B. I then use the reindex and interpolate function to calculate what would be the new values, and at the end I drop the old indexes so that I get the same array size as dummy_array-B.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create Dummy arrays
dummy_arrayA = pd.Series(np.array(range(0, 4)), index=[0,0.5,1.0,1.5])
dummy_arrayB = pd.Series(np.array(range(0, 5)), index=[0,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.6])

# Create new index based on array A
new_ind = pd.Index(dummy_arrayA.index)
# merge index A and B
new_ind=new_ind.union(dummy_arrayB.index)

# Use the reindex function. This will copy all the values and add the missing ones with nan. Then we call the interpolate function with the index method. So that it's interpolates based on the time.
df2 = dummy_arrayA.reindex(index=new_ind).interpolate(method="index")

# Delete the points.
New_ind_inter = dummy_arrayA.index.intersection(new_ind)
# We need to prevent that common point are also deleted.
new_ind = new_ind.difference(New_ind_inter)

# Delete the old points. So that the final array matchs dummy_arrayB
df2 = df2.drop(new_ind)

print(df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `np.linspace()`, `.reindex()` and `interpolate`:

The data frame `dummmy_array` is created as described above.

```
# get properties of original index
start = dummy_array.index.min()
end = dummy_array.index.max()
num_gridpoints_orig = dummy_array.index.size

# calc number of grid-points in new index
num_gridpoints_new = (num_gridpoints_orig  * 2) - 1 

# create new index, with twice the number of grid-points (i.e., smaller step-size)
idx_new = np.linspace(start, end, num_gridpoints_new)

# re-index the data frame.  New grid-points have value of NaN,
# and we replace these NaNs with interpolated values
df2 = dummy_array.reindex(index=idx_new).interpolate()

print(df2.head())

0.00   -10.0
0.05    -9.5
0.10    -9.0
0.15    -8.5
0.20    -8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of differences based on the original array. We then break it down into values and indices to create the 'pd.Series'. Join the new pd.series and reorder it.

```
# new list
ups = [[x+0.05,y+0.5] for x,y in zip(dummy_array.index, dummy_array)]
idx = [i[0] for i in ups]
val = [i[1] for i in ups]
d2 = pd.Series(val, index=idx)
d3 = pd.concat([dummy_array,d2], axis=0)
d3.sort_values(inplace=True)

d3
0.00   -10.0
0.05    -9.5
0.10    -9.0
0.15    -8.5
0.20    -8.0
0.25    -7.5
0.30    -7.0
0.35    -6.5
0.40    -6.0
0.45    -5.5
0.50    -5.0
0.55    -4.5
0.60    -4.0
0.65    -3.5
0.70    -3.0
0.75    -2.5
0.80    -2.0
0.85    -1.5
0.90    -1.0
0.95    -0.5
1.00     0.0
1.05     0.5
1.10     1.0
1.15     1.5
1.20     2.0
1.25     2.5
1.30     3.0
1.35     3.5
1.40     4.0
1.45     4.5
1.50     5.0
1.55     5.5
1.60     6.0
1.65     6.5
1.70     7.0
1.75     7.5
1.80     8.0
1.85     8.5
1.90     9.0
1.95     9.5
2.00    10.0
2.05    10.5
dtype: float64
```